# How to get refresh_token with the Box Connector in Mule

Tags: mule, box, connector, anypoint-studio, cloudhub

I'm using the **3.0.0.201609092037** version (the latest one) of the Box connector as I don't find any documentation or sample code to get the refresh token, I wrote my own flow to get it.

I achieve to execute the Authorize action with the connector and then my intension is to send a request to Box API to this url: https://api.box.com/oauth2/token in order to get an access_token and also a refresh_token (I got the API info from here https://docs.box.com/reference#token).

The problem is, once my flow has been authorized and I get access_code, and I'm using it to send it to Box I always am receiving this:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "The authorization code has expired"
}
```

I checked all the information and I it suppose to be good, the response I'm expecting is:

```
{
    "access_token": "T9cE5asGnuyYCCqIZFoWjFHvNbvVqHjl",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "restricted_to": [],
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "J7rxTiWOHMoSC1isKZKBZWizoRXjkQzig5C6jFgCVJ9bUnsUfGMinKBDLZWP9BgR"
}
```

So I'll be able to store those properties and refresh the token if is needed.

Here how my flow looks like:

[image]

and Here my XML definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw" xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting" xmlns:tls="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:objectstore="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/objectstore" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:box="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/box" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/box http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/box/current/mule-box.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/objectstore http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/objectstore/current/mule-objectstore.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls/current/mule-tls.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" protocol="HTTPS">
        <tls:context>
            <tls:key-store type="jks" path="OBKeytore.jks" keyPassword="password" password="password"/>
        </tls:context>
    </http:listener-config>
    <box:config-with-oauth name="Box__OAuth_2_0" clientId="my_client_id" clientSecret="My_secret" doc:name="Box: OAuth 2.0">
        <box:oauth-callback-config domain="localhost" localPort="8081" remotePort="8081" path="callback" connector-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration"/>
        <box:oauth-store-config objectStore-ref="_defaultInMemoryObjectStore"/>
    </box:config-with-oauth>
    <objectstore:config name="ObjectStore__Connector" partition="BoxAccessToken"  persistent="true" doc:name="ObjectStore: Connector"/>
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="api.box.com" port="443" basePath="/oauth2/" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" protocol="HTTPS"/>
    <tls:context name="TLS_Context" doc:name="TLS Context">
        <tls:trust-store path="OBKeytore.jks" password="password" type="jks"/>
        <tls:key-store type="jks" path="OBKeystore.jks" keyPassword="password" password="password"/>
    </tls:context>
    <flow name="Authorize">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/authorize" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <box:authorize config-ref="Box__OAuth_2_0" doc:name="Box"/>
        <flow-ref name="GenerateAcessToken" doc:name="GenerateAcessToken"/>
    </flow>
    <flow name="GenerateAcessToken">
        <logger message="Acess Token: #[flowVars['_oauthVerifier']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <set-payload value="#[[
    'grant_type' :'authorization_code',
    'code':flowVars['_oauthVerifier'],
    'client_id':'my_client_id',
    'client_secret':'my_secret'
]]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="token" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP">
            <http:success-status-code-validator values="200,400"/>
        </http:request>
        <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
            <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
            <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

I have to mention that I already tried to use POSTMAN with the same params, replacing the code (as far I know it is valid for 30 secs) and getting the same response.

Here some more information:

Anypoint Studio version: 6.1.1
Server Runtime: 3.8.1 EE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the OAuth authorization configuration of the HTTP requester might be required as described for a Mule Server trying to access the resources that belong to a Box user and that are held in a Box server: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/authentication-in-http-requests

http://mulesoft.github.io/box-connector/3.0.0/apidocs/box-apidoc.html#_oauth_2_0_server_to_server and this [example of managing OAuth tokens](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/using-a-connector-to-access-an-oauth-api#managing-oauth-tokens) that uses Box as an example might be worth a look if you haven't seen it.

Comment: It seems like the first time you really need to authorize the app, but later Mule connector handles to refresh the token every time as needed, as long you app is not restarted you can work without issues. Thanks @catpaws.